# creating a specific path in Netlogo for turtles to follow

Tags: path, netlogo

I am creating a Netlogo model about a zoo. I need my zoo guests (multiple turtles) to follow a circular pathway that starts at the entrance of the zoo every 24 ticks (1 tick is 1 hour in my model). It has to move around cages that hold animals because I cannot have my guests enter the areas for animals. The path doesn't have to be fast or the shortest, I just need the turtle not to stray from it. I would prefer not to use GIS to create a pathway.

My world's dimensions are -30 to 30 in both directions and does not wrap around.

The whereabouts of the cages are described below:

```
patches-own [ tigerhabitat?
              flamingohabitat?
              monkeyhabitat?
              hippohabitat?
              giraffehabitat?
            ]

to create-habitats
  ask patches with [ pxcor < -12 and pycor > 23 ]
  [ set tigerhabitat? true
    set pcolor green ]

  ask patches with [ pxcor > 20 and pycor > 20 ]
  [ set hippohabitat? true
    set pcolor blue ]

  ask patches with [ pxcor > 18 and pycor < 15 and -1 < pycor ]
  [ set flamingohabitat? true
    set pcolor 96 ]

  ask patches with [ pxcor > -10 and pxcor < 10 and pycor < 10 and -10 < pycor ]
  [ set monkeyhabitat? true
    set pcolor green ]

  ask patches with [ pxcor < -12 and pycor < -20 ]
  [ set giraffehabitat? true
    set pcolor 67 ]

end
```

Comment: Do the guests need to move only one direction along the path?

Comment: They can move in one direction (forwards).

Comment: Where is the path you want them to follow? When I `create-habitats` I do see the cages; can you give more detail as to what you have tried and why it is not doing what you want? If you just need an idea of where to start, maybe check out some of the models included in the model library. For example, [Surface Walking 2D](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/SurfaceWalking2D), the Wall Following example, or the Look Ahead model.

Comment: I don't know how to make one of my turtle breeds, the zoo guests, not go into the cages. I haven't tried anything because I don't know how to go about that. Perhaps making a strict path for the zoo guests to follow that goes around the cages.

Answer (score 1):

Paula- from your comment I think I understand a little better, thanks. One simple way to control where turtles can move is to use logical operators to exclude patches that they "consider" as they walk along. For a basic (non-path, yet) version of what you want, you could tell turtles that they can only move on patches that are not cages. You can set up a patch-only variable that explicitly says if a patch is caged or not, but in your example above all non-cage patches are black- you can use that to tell turtles that they should only walk onto a path if it is black. For example, you could add the procedures below to your code as above:

```
to setup
  ca
  reset-ticks
  crt 10 [
    setxy -25 0
  ]
  create-habitats
end


to go
  exclude-cage-walk
  tick
end


to exclude-cage-walk
  ask turtles [
    rt random 30 - 15
    let target one-of patches in-cone 1.5 180 with [ pcolor = black ]
    if target != nobody [
      face target
      move-to target
    ]
  ]
end
```

You can see that before moving forward, each turtle assesses whether or not the patch it has chosen to `move-to` is black, and if it is *not* black, the turtle will not move there. Of course, you would have to modify this to suit your needs and have the turtles walk in a one-directional circuit, but it is a simple way to constrain turtle movement.